# WebBrowser does not change

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm making an application in C# which, depending of a variable, shows one web page or another.

When I push a button, the program load the userName and the webBrowser should show a different web page. Here is my source code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string url = "http://www.url.com/" + userName;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    webBrowser1.Refresh();
}
```

The problem is that, when I push the button a second time with a different variable, the web browser reloads the same web page.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application, or WPF?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of the `webBrowser1.Refresh();` you don't need it and i think you are pushing the button 2 consecutive times with different values and it gives you the impression that it's loading another page but it isn't. try to remove that line and add an event to the Navigated method of your WebBrowser object in order to obtain a feedback when the browser is done loading the page.

Comment: Navigate is async IMHO so immediately calling `Refresh` after `Navigate` would cancel the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I had set the property AllowNavigation to false, so, when I tried to change the web page, it didn't allow me to did it. Anyway, I needed to remove the `Refresh`call to make it work.